# Signal clipping in Arduino Serial Plotter

Tags: arduino-uno, op-amp

I would like to understand why did Arduino clipped the input signal as shown in the attached diagram? As far as I know, Arduinos are able to read analogue voltages up to **5v**, that is **1023**. But for some reason my signal got clipped at **390** which is about **1.90V**. What may be the reason behind this? The schematic is also attached. The low voltage input signal **(mV range)** is passed through a Band pass filter with a gain of **143**. The signal is then DC shifted by +3.3/2=**1.65V** by using a capacitor coupled voltage divider offset. The opamp **LM358 (not LT1215 shown in the schematic)** and everything else is powered from Arduino's built in **3.3V** regulator. One reason might be that the opamp can't spit out anything more than its supply voltage, that is **3.3V**, but even then the clipping should take place at **675 (1023*3.3/5), not 390**. Am I missing something??

Thank you for reading my question. Any help is highly appreciated ^_^.

**Serial Plotter:**
[image]

**Schematic:**
[image]

Comment: LM358 is not rail-to-rail IO. You will never be able to get anything even close to 3.3V out of it.

Comment: So this is an opamp issue correct?? When 5V was supplied, clipping occurred at 600. Might have to change the opamp then, or decrease the gain of my signal??

Comment: Yep. Choose something that was designed sometime in the last 30 years.

Comment: The OPA342 or one of its derivatives might do what you want. You should read the data sheet to be sure it will do what you want.